# I can open a connection with SQL Developer but when i do the same with .NET returns me ORA-12514

Tags: oracle

In SQL Developer

[image]

In my .NET proyect, Web.config:

```
<add name="DBConection" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAcess.Client" connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 172.27.32.27)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=BDTEST1)));Password=pass;User ID=user;" />
```

When trying to connect with the application it gives me:

```
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
```

I have modify all TNSNames.ora files I could find in my pc, but the database is in another server that i cannot acces. Is the problem in my PC or is something wrong in the server that impede this connection?

**EDIT:**

This is the TNSNames.ora, in fact, all the TNSNames.ora I could find in mi PC, because I don't know what is the file the application is using, or if it is even in my pc.

```
    BDTEST1 =
   (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 172.27.32.27)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = BDTEST1) 
    )
  )
```

Comment: I'm gonna edit the question to add the TNSNames.ora.
About the SID, how it should appear in the connection string?

Comment: I edited the string. This missing 1 is a mistake, I was doing test. The error still appears.

Comment: @Sam The error clearly indicates that a connection attempt is making its way to the database server, so there is no apparent driver issue here. The connection string is simply malformed in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database instance "BDTEST1" will, by default, register service "BDTEST1" in the Oracle Listener. Oracle Listener will expose that SERVICE_NAME.

Replace `SERVICE_NAME=BDTEST` with `SERVICE_NAME=BDTEST1` for your .NET config and you can connect.

Before you enter the app layer, make sure your connect-string is correct.
use sqlplus or SQL Developer (custom connect):

```
sqlplus user/pass@\"(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 172.27.32.27)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=BDTEST1)))\"
```

If you connect using the SID the connect-string will be:

```
sqlplus user/pass@\"(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 172.27.32.27)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)(SID=BDTEST1)))\"
```

I think you have to escape the " on Windows...not sure.

Side note: Behind a service there can be multiple oracle database hosts and DR hosts. If you connect using SID, you will always connect to the named instance (SID). If this one is down, no failover can happen. So you better use SERVICE_NAME. Ask you admins to provide it to you.

Best of luck!

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I was making test and when making the question forguet to put it again. The error persist. I will edit my question to put BDTEST1, like I have in my code. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Observation: You are using "Basic" connection type in SQL Developer, and a direct connection with .NET, neither of which actually use tnsnames.ora, or you wouldn't be putting the host information in your connect strings at all.

That said, you are using ORACLE_SID=BDTEST1 in your SQL Developer connection and SERVICE_NAME=BDTEST1 in your .NET connection.

1. Don't just assume which service names should be registered. Confirm which service names are *actually* registered with your Oracle listener using the "lsnrctl status" or "lsnrctl services" commands.
2. Either change your .NET connect string to use a registered service_name, or change "SERVICE_NAME=" to "SID=" in your .NET connect string (because you've proved that works with SQL Developer).

If you really want to use tnsnames.ora, then in SQL Developer use a connection type of "TNS" and specify a Connect Identifier of "BDTEST1" to match what's in your tnsnames.ora file; and for .NET modify your connect string to be the following:

```
connectionString="Data Source=BDTEST1;Password=pass;User ID=user;"
```